# jQuery dynatree Tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynatree

Using jQuery and Dynatree, I am trying to get the dynatree tooltip behavior like the jQuery normal tooltip.

Did anyone get that? As for what I am getting to do, the dynatree tooltip is just the default HTLM little yellow tooltip.

The following piece of code isn't doing it either.

> ```
>           $("#my_tree").dynatree("option", {
>                 initAjax:{
>                     url: my_url,
>                     data: my_data,
>                 },
>                 onPostInit: function(){
>                     $(".dynatree-title").tooltip();
>                 }
> ```

If you see the html generated by Dynatree, the nodes containing a title have that `.dynatree-title` style. But not even putting the `$(".dynatree-title").tooltip();` in the callback it gets the jQuery tooltip look.

Did anyone get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget it. I was using the wrong callback method.

The right one is onCreate or onRender.

I hope this help someone.

Comment: Is there another way to do it? I'm updating stuff in my tree and I want the tooltip to update without having to refresh the tree.

Comment: If I am not wrong, you can go like: $("#id").tooltip('destroy').tooltip(); previously having changed the data-title attribute of the element. I hope this works. But all this has nothing to do with dynatree, but with JQuery tooltip instead.